Modbus RS485 with Gateway on debian an Python3
I would like to use python to read/write using Modbus RTU on multiple equipment: 4 equipments. ID 1 to 4.
I am used to do that with a PLC (Programmable Logic Controller), but this time I need to do it with a computer on Debian with a RTU halfDuplex. The name of the device is : /dev/ttymxc0
Each equipment has 3x 20 registers to read.
I would like to read it each 5 secondes, if one is not working I still want to be able to read the other one. It should be an open loop reading those registers.
I decided to use a async modbus rtu connection.
I tried to used pymodbus but nothing was working, I got not data. When I used modpoll it is working.
I tried minimalModbus, which is working but I got a lot of error : see picture.
My code is the following one:
[import asyncio import minimalmodbus

async def read_input_registers_async():
    # Configure the serial port
    instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('/dev/ttymxc0', 1)  # Port name, slave address
    instrument.serial.baudrate = 38400                         # Baud rate
    instrument.serial.bytesize = 8
    instrument.serial.parity   = minimalmodbus.serial.PARITY_NONE
    instrument.serial.stopbits = 1
    instrument.serial.timeout  = 1                            # seconds

    instrument.mode = minimalmodbus.MODE_RTU                   # RTU mode

    try:
        # Perform the Modbus read operation asynchronously
        units_addresses = \[
          (1, 0, 10),
          (1, 10, 10),
          (1, 20, 10),
          # Add more (unit, address, count) tuples as needed
        \]
        for unit, address, count in units_addresses:
          input_registers = await asyncio.to_thread(instrument.read_registers, address, count, functioncode=4)  # Start address, number of registers, function code 4
          print(f"Input registers: {input_registers}")
    except IOError:
        print("Failed to read from instrument")
    finally:
        #instrument.serial.close()
        print("Failed to read from instrument")

async def main():
    while True:
        await read_input_registers_async()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)  # Adjust interval as needed

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())][1]

How can I do something better ? I feel that I am not dealing correctly with the rs485 bus. Sometime it is going verry fast and sometime verry slow.
Loic

Does it work consistently when doing a single read to a single device? Modbus over a serial cable does not work naturally with threading, each communication needs to be allowed to run to completion before the next one is attempted, so asyncio.to_thread will cause issues. You need to decouple the entire serial port handling, not individual reads.
